# Is it possible to clone phone to anohter phone with same model using TWRP?

Tags: backup, twrp, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have Samsung S7 and I have made whole backup of it to my sdcard - system, data, chache, etc. One day that phone broke and I am going to buy new one with same model. Will it work if I restore backup from sdcard to a new phone? I don't know if the new phone have same ROM, but if it needed then I can install it because I still have it on my computer.

Comment: It should work as long as both phones have identical OS versions. Two points 1. Take care not to restore EFS and other partitions that are device specific 2. Restoring data should be enough. I had done a similar thing with two note 2 devices way back. I won't make this an answer because I am not aware of latest Samsung things but in principle, no problem

Comment: If the backup of the user data partition in decrypted or encrypted format? As the device encryption usually uses hardware based encryption cloning the user data partition in encrypted form should not work. If it is decrypted and you restore it the system may be confused as it expects an encrypted partition. But those are just theoretical thoughts, I don't have any practical experience with closing partitions.

Comment: @Robert very valid point. Didn't consider that

Comment: Disk dump of encrypted partition is problematic but TWRP backs up decrypted `userdata` partition using `tar` (or we can do from commandline if TWRP is able to decrypt FDE/FBE). But the hardware-specific things are more trouble e.g. the databases which contain IMEI or other identifiers need to be updated. Similarly things dependent on TEE cannot be backed up e.g. fingerprint. Better is to just back up the selective things like settings, apps data, personal data etc.

Comment: just prepare your current phone to be ready creating a fresh backup via adb shell for the day the screen will be broken